# What are the default options for a @property declaration in ARC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting

If i have the following in my .h file:

```
@property UIButton *connect;
```

Is this the same as:

```
@property(atomic, strong) UIButton *connect;
```

Eg what are the default 'arguments' in an @property declaration?

Comment: You can also have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362157/why-are-cocoas-iboutlet-properties-atomic-by-default-and-cocoa-touchs-arent/15362414#15362414

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, properties default to `atomic` and `strong`.

[Properties are Atomic by Default](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW37)

[Use Strong and Weak Declarations to Manage Ownership](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW30) - see the next sentence.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm teaching iOS development at the moment, and figured that it'd be easier to just teach the @property method without the 'arguments' - just wanted to make sure they were sensible defaults.

Comment: @Downvoter - why the down vote? The question is answered correctly with links to the documentation.

Comment: Yes , at least leave some comment before downvoting. Otherwise that is something like negative mentality.

Comment: @rmaddy: I dint downvote. But still I am confused...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362157/why-are-cocoas-iboutlet-properties-atomic-by-default-and-cocoa-touchs-arent/15362414#15362414

Comment: @AnoopVaidya The docs state that properties are atomic by default. What's the confusion?

Comment: but for outlets it is non-atomic and weak, and even outlets are properties. And I have checked in XC4.3- it was atomic, in XC4.4+ it is non-atomic. Am I wrong?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Is this documented anywhere? I don't use IB so I have no idea of outlets are treated differently.

Comment: Dont know about doucumentation but when I use storyboard, and drag from a UIButton to .h it creates as non-atomic.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya But that's an explicit declaration, right? In other words, is `non-atomic` explicitly added to the `@property`? If so then that has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: I dont have much idea about this. And i think someone downvoted on this ground only.

Comment: Hey @rmaddy, thanks a lot for the links, totally appreciated. Ignore the haters that have taken over this site :)

Answer (score 2):

**strong** and **atomic** is the default option in the property declaration see this link:[link](http://openradar.appspot.com/11071507)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `atomic` and `strong` are default attributes. It seems to be spread out in the docs though it took a longer than I thought to find:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Answer (score 1):

by default properties are atomic as documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW37) and are strong as mentioned [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW22) (see just above the 'avoid strong reference cycles')